# wordpress data for buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have data for buddypress in table named "`wp_bp_xprofile_data`" which has fields like

> "a:2:{i:0;s:10:"myproject";i:1;s:5:"Other";}"

What kind of data it is ? surely its not JSON ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's PHP serialised data. You can parse it out with `unserialize()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Thanks James. I tried to accept your answer but getting "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes
(click on this box to dismiss)" ..... :P :(

Comment: maybe you should try again now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Re serialized profile data:

```
$value = bp_get_profile_field_data(‘field=some_serialized_field’);
$value = bp_unserialize_profile_field($value);
```